# R: Why does sum(X, rm.na=TRUE) != sum(X, rm.na=FALSE) for a filled array?

Tags: r

Ok, I'm stumped on this one.  Why is R behaving like this?  The array is full...

> sum(array(10, dim = c(2, max(50,50))),rm.na=TRUE)

[1] 1001

> sum(array(10, dim = c(2, max(50,50))),rm.na=FALSE)

[1] 1000

Comment: With `na.rm=TRUE` or `FALSE`, it returns `1000`  `sum(..., na.rm = FALSE)` from the help files and not `rm.na`

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you meant `na.rm` not `rm.na`. You are doing the equivalent of

```
sum(array(10, dim = c(2, max(50,50))),TRUE)
```

which is 1000 + 1 (i.e., 1000 for your array, 1 for the TRUE value).

What you meant to do was:

```
> sum(array(10, dim = c(2, max(50,50))), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1000
```

Or more simply in this case (removing the `max(50,50)` which I assume comes from a wider context):

```
> sum(array(10, dim = c(2, 50)), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1000
```