# What does rm.na argument in sum() mean?

Tags: r, sum, arguments

I had a typo and wrote `sum(vec, rm.na= TRUE)` instead of `sum(vec, na.rm= TRUE)`. I noticed this typo because the sums were wrong. For example, for `sum(0.5, rm.na= TRUE)` the sum is `1.5`. That is weird to me. What is the `rm.na` argument for?

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789831/r-why-does-sumx-rm-na-true-sumx-rm-na-false-for-a-filled-array) with `sum(..., rm.na= TRUE)` but in that question the person was not aware of the typo and the answer doesn't clarify what the argument does (at least I don't get it). So I am puzzled by this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting a bit from the answer for the question you linked:

It's because you meant `na.rm` not `rm.na`. You are doing the equivalent of

```
sum(0.5, 1)
> 1.5

sum(0.5, TRUE)
> 1.5

sum(0.5, rm.na = TRUE)
> 1.5

sum(0.5, na.rm = TRUE)
> 0.5
```

Any parameter with a name different from `na.rm` is included in the sum. The value `TRUE` is included as integer `1`.

Comment: Said slightly differently: because the formal definition is `(..., na.rm = FALSE)`, anything other than `na.rm=` is included in the `...` ellipses and therefore converted (if possible) to numbers and included in the sum.

Comment: Interestingly, not in all functions new variables are automatically created when using `rm.na=TRUE` inside. For example, `mean(TRUE)` returns `1` but `mean(rm.na=TRUE)` returns an error. Wondering why `sum` sees `rm.na=TRUE` as a new variable defined inside the function but `mean` doesn't.

Comment: The `mean` function does not average multiple arguments while `sum` does. Thus `mean(0,1)` is `0` as it uses only the first argument.

Comment: In contrast to `sum`, `mean` has the formal definition `(x, ...) `, and the mean is taken from the `x` argument while non-existing arguments (in sub-routines) get ignored.